# Explanation for the "I am whole but incomplete..." riddle?

Tags: riddle, explanation

I saw a riddle:

I am whole but incomplete,
I have no eyes, yet I see.
You can see, and see right through me.
My largest part is one fourth of what I once was.
What am I?

Apparently the answer is:

> A skeleton

but I don't understand it.  How does it "see"?  How is its largest part one fourth of what it once was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am whole but incomplete

This means a skeleton is whole considering it as a structure. But it is just a part of the body. So it's incomplete.

> I have no eyes, yet I see.
>   You can see, and see right through me.

This means skeletons don't have eyes - just the holes. By yet I can 'see' it refers to the 'see' in the word '**s**'k'**e**'l'**e**'ton. The same is meant by 'you can see', and 'see right through me'. Which makes it clear that we can see the word 'see' in (right through) '**s**k**e**l**e**ton'.

(Or as mentioned in the comments: people perceive a skeleton to "see" through its eye sockets, even though it no longer has eyes.  And people can see through the gaps in a skeleton.)

> My largest part is one fourth of what I once was.

The largest part of a skeleton is the femur, which is one fourth of the body (which the skeleton once was) in length.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: The "see" thing seems like a bit of a stretch.  I still don't understand the "one fourth" part.  1/4 by mass?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: I think "see" refers to the fact that if you point a skeleton at you... and in fiction... the skeleton would seem to be able to actually see you.

Comment: @jamesdlin: It's not 1/4 by mass. But by length.

Comment: The femur, or thigh bone, is the longest and heaviest bone in the body. Its length varies from one fourth to one third of that of the body;

Comment: also, you can see through a skeleton because there are gaps eg between the ribs

Comment: @KateGregory that's what i thought as well.